# Trouble displaying text over background image in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to display text over this background image using React.js. Not sure if I am missing code in my App.js file? or css file?

this is what I have in my App.js file so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <div id="port">
        <div id="name">
          <p>Nicole M. Cuellar</p>
        </div>
      </div>

  );
}
```

this is in my css file:

```js
#port {
  background-image: url('../images/largebulb.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -10;
}

 #name {
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -40;
}
```

Comment: Do you require #name to be a child of #port? If not you could set up as siblings and this easy css works.  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CSS issue, this isn't a node issue. I've attached some quick direction for thought.

```css
#port {
  z-index: -10;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568050231220-41aae5663af6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="port">
  <div id="name">
    <p>Nicole M. Cuellar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```